# How to output a zipfile in Luigi Task?

Tags: python, pipeline, luigi

It is ok to `output()` zip files like this:

```
def output(self):
    date_path = self.search['date_path']
    zip_fn = "data/%s/%s.zip" % (date_path, date_path)
    return luigi.LocalTarget(zip_fn)
```

But how to pas this zip in `run()` method?

```
class ZeroTask(luigi.Task):
    path_in = luigi.Parameter()
    textfiles = []
    path_to_zip = ''

    def requires(self):
        return []

    def run(self):

       # Get a bunch of text files
       # Do some manipulations with textfiles
       # Create a result.zip
       # self.path_to_zip = '~/Project/result.zip'

    def output(self):
        zip_fn = self.path_to_result.zip
        return luigi.LocalTarget(zip_fn)
```

What should I do in the `run()` method?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `zipfile` to build the file however you'd like.

```
class MyTask(luigi.Task):
    def output(self):
      date_path = self.search['date_path']
      zip_fn = "data/%s/%s.zip" % (date_path, date_path)
      return luigi.LocalTarget(zip_fn)

     def run(self):
        ztemp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb')
        z = zipfile.ZipFile(ztemp, 'w')

        #  build the zip file

        z.close()
        os.rename(ztemp.name, self.output().path)
```

From [the docs on FileSystemTarget](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.target.html#luigi.target.FileSystemTarget),